# alarm: calling an status bar notification activity doesn't work

Tags: android

```
 private void scheduleAlarmReceiver() {
 AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, StatusNotify.class),
 PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
 alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 2000,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
 Log.i("alarm", "alarm set");
 }
```

statusnotify.class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_status_notify);
 NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 int unique_id = 145558;
 Log.i("status bar" +unique_id , " ");
 Intent nintent = new Intent();
 nintent.setClass(this, TaskTrace.class);
 PendingIntent pin = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0, nintent, 0);
 String title = "Notification";
 String body = "This is a new notification";
 Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body, System.currentTimeMillis());
 n.contentIntent = pin;
 n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), title, body, pin);
 n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
 nm.notify(unique_id, n);
 }
```

Statusnotify works fine when run individually but doesn't get trigered from the alarm class.

guess everything is fine in the intent call. Please do help me out. satus bar notifiction must appear 1n 2 seconds when the alarm is set and repeat for every day in same time